# Does artifactory keep a record of downloads?

Tags: artifactory

I've looked in the jfrog docs unsuccessfully for this. It would be really nice to see how many folk have downloaded something we uploaded to our artifactory.

Answer (score 2):

You can view the download count from UI as well as from REST API.

1. UI > Navigate to artifact from tree view > General tab > Number of downloads will be visible.
2. Using REST API.

curl -u admin -X GET "https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/storage/my-repository/org/jfrog/0.1/myjar-0.1.jar?stats"

This will result the following output.

```
{
  "uri" : "https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/storage/my-repository/org/jfrog/0.1/myjar-0.1.jar",
  "downloadCount" : 11,
  "lastDownloaded" : 1666979645447,
  "lastDownloadedBy" : "admin",
  "remoteDownloadCount" : 0,
  "remoteLastDownloaded" : 0
}
```

Comment: Testing this approach to get statistics, we observe unexpected huge differences between the numbers we get from API and the numbers through the UI. Any idea why this could happen ?